# How do i shut fancybox iframe after a submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, fancybox

I have an iframe on siteB with has a from from siteA when the user on siteB clicks on the submit

```
<input type="submit" value="Save url" name="commit" method="post" id="url_submit">
```

I need the lightbox to close

i tried adding

```
$('#url_submit').click(function(){
  $.fn.fancybox.close();
});
```

to both sites and nothing and i am sort of confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, are siteA and siteB under the same domain? If so, you can try

```
window.parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();
```

But if they're not, you'll have to create a callback url that closes your fancybox, and when your form is submitted redirect to this url.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            window.parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

Comment: This is working for me, but it's closing the window before the POST can get to the server, there is any way of delaying it?

Answer (score 1):

Figured a great solution that is really clean added

```
 TARGET="_top"
```

and it closed after submission

Answer (score 0):

Little confused by your question. Can you open firebug and do `$.fn.fancybox.close();` ?